# How to force MySQL to return limited rows?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I would like to limit the results from mysql query submitted by users.
Currently I am just parsing query string by PHP then appending `LIMIT` in the end.
For more complex queries with many nested selects/joins the things are becoming complex and less predictable.
Are there common way to force mysql to return only limited results even if user has asking for full set?

Thanks
Arman

Comment: LIMIT is the correct way to do. What exactly are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I have a 4Tb table, but at once I would like to allow to retrieve maximum 50 rows. The users are allowed to access in read only mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for some server configuration settings to limit the maximum number of rows returned by all queries. That is, `select * from mytable` will return maximum x number (x is set in global server configuration) or rows even there are many more rows in the table.

Unfortunately, this is not possible in standard distributions of MySQL. You can set limits on maximum queries per hour, even what operations a user can do in server. But, limit of number of rows in query result cannot be set globally.

However, you can get the MySQL community edition source code and add a configuration for global query result limit.
Also, if you are using some kind of connector to connect to MySQL (for example, if you are connecting to MySQL from .NET), you can leave the server as is but modify the connector code and add your desired limiting configuration option there.

Comment: thanks for tips, I am using PHP:PDO connector but again I need to write sql parser to add limits.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: [Set a default LIMIT in PDO/MySQL when no LIMIT is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983816/set-a-default-limit-in-pdo-mysql-when-no-limit-is-set), it is possible to limit the maximal number of returned records using the MySQL setting 'sql_select_limit':

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_select_limit

This setting is available from at-least MySQL 5.6.